# What is a GINA dll

Tags: c#, gina

What is a GINA dll, and is it possible to trap special key combinations using this dll? How can I use this in a kiosk application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GINA handles part of the login and authentication process for interactive logins on a Windows machine for versions prior to Vista (it has since been replaced by the [`ICredentialProvider` interface](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925520)).

In general, I wouldn't advocate writing a replacement GINA (or credential provider) in .Net, as you'd inject a dependency on the .Net framework into the Winlogon process - one slip, and you could end up with a machine that refuses to boot.

Comment: oks..so its basically not advisable to use it,,in my application i have to avoid the usage of special key combination.and all... is there any other method which will not harm system or Os

Comment: No. The three finger press (CTRL-ALT-DEL) is specifically made to be NOT INTERRUPTABLE by an application - it actually never sees it, the kernel directly moves to the secure surface (separate session) for security reasons.

Comment: then how is it possible to disable such tasks in kiosk application... any way user should not perform such tasks ....if perform have to handle that so...pls help with ur views

Comment: @deepukj You're going to have to get dirty with some native code, either building a native GINA/ICredentialProvider or bespoking a system based on (perhaps) a Linux kernel.

Comment: It is simple: unplug the keyboard.  You can lock down the machine with the group policy editor, ask questions about it at superuser.com